# Expect command not working for logging in

Tags: unix, ksh, expect

Im trying to call a remote function in another unix machine (lets call machine2), and i need to log in everytime i want to call it from machine1. So im trying to user the command expect to do so. (do not suggest using ssh keys please, that option is discarted).

So this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/bin/ksh

ssh user@machine2 data/test.sh

expect "Password:"

send "pass001\n"
```

and this is the error returned:

```
invalid command name "ssh"
    while executing
"ssh user@machine2 data/test.sh"
    (file "testscript.ksh" line 4)
```

---- Update->
When i change the code and add the spawn command, it still would return an error:

new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/bin/ksh

spawn ssh user@machine2 data/test.sh

expect "Password:"

send "pass001\r"
```

error turned:

```
sh: /usr/local/bin/stty: not found
```

Comment: Expect requires you to `spawn` a process that it can control.

Answer (score 1):

Please include `spawn`. 
The `spawn` command spawns or launches an external command for you. In this case, `ssh` to a remote host (`aspen`):

```
spawn ssh aspen
```

Comment: I included spawn and still get the same error... related to stty

Comment: what does your data/test.sh file contain

Comment: The issue was with stty, i had to get i installe for my user... thanks anyway for your time!